# how to unstack or unpivot a pandas dataframe based on conditional row values?

Tags: pandas, unpivot

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

But I need to pull out table and chair into their own columns to compare side by side like so:

[image]

so the values in amount are zero, and now appear in the new columns.

I am not sure how to unstack conditionally.  I can unstack the entire 'furniture' column, but how do I do it for only specific row values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `get_dummies`

```
df = df.join(df.furniture.where(df.furniture.isin(["table","chair"]),'amount').str.get_dummies().mul(df.pop("amount"),0))
df
Out[87]: 
   CID furniture  amount  chair  table
0    1     couch       2      0      0
1    2     couch       3      0      0
2    2     chair       0      1      0
3    3     table       0      0      3
4    1     chair       0      1      0
5    4      lamp       5      0      0
6    4     chair       0      1      0
7    5     couch       2      0      0
8    2      lamp       5      0      0
```

Comment: After I posted I thought to myself, I could unstack the entire column, set index and then stack only desired ones, but this is much cleaner.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mask and then use boolean indexing:

```
m_table = df["furniture"] == "table"
m_chair = df["furniture"] == "chair"

df["table"] = np.where(m_table, df["amount"], 0)
df["chair"] = np.where(m_chair, df["amount"], 0)

df.loc[m_table | m_chair, "amount"] = 0
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   CID furniture  amount  table  chair
0    1     couch       2      0      0
1    2     couch       3      0      0
2    2     chair       0      0      1
3    3     table       0      3      0
4    1     chair       0      0      1
5    4      lamp       5      0      0
6    4     chair       0      0      1
7    5     couch       2      0      0
8    2      lamp       5      0      0
```